# Discord.js | Fetching data when bot has been added to a new server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is this safe to be added on the function once you added a bot to a server or I can be abused?
I'm kinda scared of getting banned or rate limited So I want to make sure that everything is safe. Currently the fetch in Docs v12 is not that well documented and lack of infos about this. All I know is it fetch all data to the server. The reason I need this is to get all of the information like roles, members, etc because when trying to list all members that has the specific role all try to list members without roles it require me to fetch data since if I don't instead of members(100) it will only fetch like members(3) since the cache is not yet ready or data is not fully loaded to the cache.

```js
        await message.guild.members.fetch()
        .then(console.log)
```

Currently I have this command /fetch which will fetch the data with a 1 hour cooldown. I am planning to remove this and add it to "once they added the bot" function. I use this fetch to instances/commands like listing users without roles

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.array().length < 2).map(member => member.user.tag);
```

If you have like recommendation or a better way to do this you can check the project at [PruneBot/commands/custom](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot/tree/master/commands/custom) where full code of this is included:

- [fetch data](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot/blob/master/commands/custom/fetch.js)
- [kick no role](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot/blob/master/commands/custom/knorole.js)
- [kick users with specific role](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot/blob/master/commands/custom/krole.js)
- [list users without role](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot/blob/master/commands/custom/unorole.js)
- [list users with specific role](https://github.com/mashwishi/PruneBot/blob/master/commands/custom/urole.js)

Comment: you can try fetching it inside the ready.js event once every 6 or 7 hours using setInterval to avoid abuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a large scale bot, that is joining many servers then you might have issues with this call, but if you're not having this issue, then you can pull it when the bot is added to a server, by putting it in the guildCreate event handler.  Something like:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild=> {
guild.members.fetch()....
```